# libcurl post request from debian 7 to debian 9 gnutls handshake error

Tags: debian, curl, ssl, http

I have a problem with libcurl returning an SSL error, let me describe the situation:

There are two machines with Debian, the client is Debian 7 and the server is Debian 9, the client uses libcurl to send HTTP request via C code (both machines are local so I have `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` and `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` set to false on the client) and there is a PHP script on the server that the request is directed at. After every try I'm getting an SSL connection error :

```
gnutls_handshake() failed: A TLS fatal alert has been received
```

even though I can get the response with no problem using curl on the command line with `-k`.

Worth noting is the fact, that everything seems to not be working only if serves is deb9 and client is deb7. So:

- debian7 server debian7 client - works
- debian7 server debian9 client - works
- debian9 server debian9 client - works
- debian9 server debian7 client - doesn't work

Comment: Can you debug the PHP?

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this, how do I do that exactly? The php code only connects to database and inserts some values

Comment: Place an echo before the call to the database, an echo during the call to the database, and an echo after, on one system that works, and then on the system that doesn't, and compare the differences. [How to Debug in PHP](https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-debug-in-php).  After doing that, compare versions of curl, wget, php etc between the versions that work and the one that doesn't.

Comment: Okay I'm not getting any response, only the gnutls handshake error. Also it's running fine when client is debian 9 instead of 7 so i think that eliminates the php issue?

Comment: So I would check the GNUTLS version on Debian 7 Server and Debian 9 Server.  As a test, upgrade the version on 7 to 9's version if possible.  If the error then appears, downgrade the version on 9 to match the version on 7.  By debugging the PHP, you'll find the difference in how the handshake call is made.  I wasn't implying that the PHP was broken.

Comment: SSLv3 has been deprecated, could be it?

Comment: @eyoung100 ill try to run older version on debian9, I dont know if i can do that though

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro so is there a way to force it to use tls1.2 for example?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro possibly, that is a likely culprit if downgrading Debian 9 to match 7 works.

Comment: Does this help? [Everything Curl: TLS](https://ec.haxx.se/usingcurl-tls.html).

Comment: @eyoung100 we do not know your PHP code....not sure.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I didn't write it, but the OP can pass a TLS version in the `curl` command.

Comment: So I tried to use curl command and specify to use sslv3 istead of tls. As expected there is a sslv3 alert handshake failure

Comment: Problem resolved, turnes out i needed to recompile curl to use openssl instead of gnutls because nginx no longer supports gnutls, now everything works like a charm :)

Comment: @TesterV Both implement TLS, could not be a symptom rather than the cause? Anyway, as long as it solves your problem...